# Why does addEventListener fire before the event if at all?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, event-handling, addeventlistener

I was experimenting [in jsfiddle] w/a function created to append a newly created `TextNode` to the `<p>` in the HTML below:

```
    <button onclick="addTextNode('YES! ');">YES!</button>
    <button onclick="addTextNode('NO! ');">NO!</button>
    <button onclick="addTextNode('WE CAN! ');">WE CAN!</button>
    <hr />
    <p id="p1">First line of paragraph.</p>
```

Here is my javascript as well:

```
    function addTextNode(text) {
        var newtext = document.createTextNode(text),
            p1 = document.getElementById("p1");

        p1.appendChild(newtext);
    }
```

This works fine. However, the crux reveals itself when I attempt to make my javascript 'unobtrusive' by removing the behavior from the markup...

```
    <button>YES!</button>
    <button>NO!</button>
    <button>WE CAN!</button>
    <hr />
    <p id="p1">First line of paragraph.</p>
```

then utilizing a loop to attach `addEventListener` to each `<button>` element, which in turn uses the child `TextNode` to call `addTextNode`:

```
    function addTextNode(text) {
        var newtext = document.createTextNode(text),
            p1 = document.getElementById("p1");

        p1.appendChild(newtext);
    }

    var btns = document.getElementsByTagName("button");

    for(i = 0; i < btns.length; i++){
        var button = btns[i]; 
        button.addEventListener("click", addTextNode(button.innerHTML));
    }
```

Two strange things happen with my code:

When [jsfiddle's] [Code Wrap](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html#frameworks-and-extensions) is set to 'no wrap - in head', nothing happens.

However, When [Code Wrap](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html#frameworks-and-extensions) is set to 'onLoad', 'onDomReady' or 'no wrap - in body' the function runs before the click and I get [this](http://jsfiddle.net/js_test/6r6DV/).

Could someone tell me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The root of your problem is here:

```
button.addEventListener("click", addTextNode(button.innerHTML))
```

You're executing the function rather than passing it to the event listener. Instead, pass the function by reference, then get the innerHTML inside the function.

```
function addTextNode() {
    var newtext = document.createTextNode(this.innerHTML),
        p1 = document.getElementById("p1");

    p1.appendChild(newtext);
}

var btns = document.getElementsByTagName("button");

for(i = 0; i < btns.length; i++){
    var button = btns[i]; 
    button.addEventListener("click", addTextNode);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bn85J/

Comment: I accepted your answer for succinctness. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Answer for duplicate question suggests:
`button.addEventListener("click", function(){ addTextNode(button.innerHTML)})`.

Comment: @alexkovelsky and? they both work.

Comment: @KevinB - My comment shows that it's possible to call handler with a parameter. That's a big difference.

Comment: @alexkovelsky well, no, the handler in your case is `function () {}`. which then calls another function

Comment: @KevinB for end-user it looks like he adds listener that would call `addTextNode(parameter)` - where `parameter` is passed to `addTextNode`. In my case I needed to call `addTextNode` from different elements, with different parameter each time, depending on the element. So I used `element1.addEventListener("click", function(){ addTextNode(parameter1)})`, `element2.addEventListener("click", function(){ addTextNode(parameter2)})`
This approach might have been obvious to you, but I don't use JS very often, and it took some minutes for me to get this.

Answer (score 1):

First, your usage of Add Event listener is wrong.  add event listener is expecting a function reference in the second parameter not a function call.

The following is a function reference:

```
var myfunctionreference = addTextNode;
```

This is a function call and will execute the function

```
var myfunctioncall = addTextNode();
```

In your code you are actually calling the function to use as the event handler instead of referencing it.
Here is some Reference for [.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)

You should be binding the event like this:

```
button.addEventListener("click", addTextNode);
```

Second, the event knows the element and knows the event.  Your function call should be created to accept the event and not an arbitrary string.  Then utilizing the event or "this" will allow you to get your hands on the text your looking for.

```
function addTextNode(evt) {
    var newtext = document.createTextNode(this.innerHTML),
        p1 = document.getElementById("p1");

    p1.appendChild(newtext);
}
```